# How to get all existed steam IDs?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I am planning to create steam users database for some personal use. So my plan is to make requests on steam API with steam IDs and save the result in my database. But I have one problem I don't have steam IDs of all registered profiles.

I've tried learning how those IDs are generated but I didn't understand anything. I also tried finding the existing list of steam IDs but couldn't.
[How steam IDs are generated](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID)

Since steam has 100,000 daily limit I can't go from 000000000000000001 to 999999999999999999 that would take too much resource and time.

Can someone explain how I can get all of the existing IDs, please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've said that you've tried learning how the IDs are generated. Can you give us a link to the web page(s) that you were reading? Let's see if someone can help.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the link.

Comment: Why would Steam be interested in giving you a full copy of their users list?

Comment: How is this related to my question? I didn't say that steam would straight-up give it to me? I want to find some way to somehow get it. If not the full list at least get the majority.

Comment: Steam's API limits are intended to prevent that sort of thing.

Comment: Why use API at all? You can just send regular `https` requests and get user ID even from the private profiles by appending `?xml=1` to the address. The 64 bit ID is the first entry in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

The Steam Web API limit and the huge number for the steam ID are designed to prevent this sort of scraping of personal data.

You accepted the Steam Terms of Use and the Steam Web API terms of use which means you entered into a contract between you and Valve. In the eyes of the european data protection regulation, which is mentioned in those documents, the steam ID can be considered personal data. So what you are intending to do is against the interest of Valve and their user's rights for privacy.

From a technical standpoint there is no way to get all steam IDs unless you try all possible variations for a SteamID64.

Comment: Wrong. Steam ID is a public information, even for the private profiles.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you somehow missed this part in the linked wiki page:

```
Using the reverse methods, a Community ID can be converted to a regular SteamID.
The value of Z can be retrieved by checking parity of the number W:
if it's even, Y is 0, if it's odd, Y is 1 (shortly,
Y is the remainder of division of W by 2, or the result of binary AND operation with number 1).

The SteamID64 (64-bit SteamID) of Steam Community members can be found in several places:

    Players:
        In profile->steamID64 element of profile XML schema (can be opened by appending ?xml=1 to profile URL).
        In the "Add to your friends list" link
        (not recommended to be used in applications that login with username and password).
    Groups: in the "Enter chat room" link.
```

To get all the steam IDs you don't even need to use API at all. You can just crawl steam friend lists using regular `https` requests, there should be no limit on that. To get `steamID64` from a profile page, append `?xml=1` to the full profile URL. This will give you XML file that will have `steamID64` as a first entry.

After you finished crawling all the friend lists, you can start testing ID's that where not found to check if there is some sneaky users with no friends.

And voila, you have all the steam IDs! Of course, only up to the date you finish your crawl. I'm not sure if it is possible too keep this database up to date.